# How to have certain buttons and balance show after login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, authentication

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  border-bottom: 5px #FF9F00 solid;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

#logo img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 42.5px;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
}

.beforelogin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.afterlogin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#rightnavbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar,
li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  position: relative;
}

#rightnavbar a:hover {
  color: #FF9F00;
}

#rightnavbar a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FF9F00;
  position: absolute;
  top: -34px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 225ms;
}

#rightnavbar a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

#userbalance {
  background-color: #23272A;
  padding: 12.5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2.5px #FF9F00 solid;
}

#balance,
#dsh {
  color: #FF9F00;
}

#dosh {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div id="logo">

    <a href="index.html"><img src="./img/logo.png" title="Website Info"></img>
    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="beforelogin">

    <div id="rightnavbar">

      <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html">Login</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="afterlogin">

    <div class="navbar">

      <div id="leftnavbar">

        <ul>

          <li id="userbalance"><span id="balance">Balance:</span> <span id="dosh">1.00000000</span> <span id="dsh">DSH</span></li>

        </ul>

      </div>

      <div id="rightnavbar">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="index.html">User Panel</a></li>

          <li><a href="index.html">News</a></li>

          <li><a href="index.html">View on Social Media</a></li>

          <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</header>
```

I am trying to make my website, where after user logs in `.beforelogin`'s `<li>` disappears and `.afterlogin`'s `<li>` appears.

So there is only `Login` button for the user till the user logs in (In the header/navbar) and after login the `Login` exchanges its place for `Logout` and 3 other buttons and User Balance appears.

I asked a webdev friend and he said to use JavaScript/jQuery but I am not that good in those. I am still trying to find some good tutorials to learn JavaScript/jQuery for webdev but I am not sure where to look for.

Answer (score 1):

As per above HTML you can use below code to hide containers based on logged in and logged out  scenarios.

1) User non logged in scenario

```
$(".beforelogin").show();
$(".afterlogin").hide();
```

2) User logged in scenario.

```
$(".afterlogin").show();
$(".beforelogin").hide();
```

Of course we should call above functions at right place in the code and logged in and non logged in scenario should be dependent on login service call, but it depends on the requirement. And also to draw containers (afterlogin, beforelogin) at same location you have to use similar styling.

Comment: Can you tell me where or how to use this on my code? I mean my friend gave me a similar code but I don't know what to do with it; where to place it. I assume its in my app.js but not sure how; as I am not even sure how to link my app.js in my html like my style.css

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp   go through  this link and you will be a champ in jquery in a day,  Mark this as answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be some trigger that executes this script. In this case you can add this HTML temporarily under the header

```
<br />
<input type="radio" name="loginStatus" id="loggedIn" value="Logged in" checked="checked" /> User is logged in
<br />
<input type="radio" name="loginStatus" id="loggedOut" value="Logged out" /> User is logged out
```

Now the jQuery:

```
// sets initial status - this can be done by CSS as well
if ($('input#loggedIn').prop('checked')) {
  alert('Login is visible so after-loggin is hidden');
  $('.beforelogin').css('display', 'none');
  $('.afterlogin').css('display', 'block');
} else {
  alert('Login is visible so after-loggin is hidden');
  $('.beforelogin').css('display', 'block');
  $('.afterlogin').css('display', 'none');
}
// this changes the status based on the radio buttons
$('input[name = "loginStatus"]').change(function() {
  if ($('input#loggedIn').prop('checked')) {
    $('.beforelogin').css('display', 'none');
    $('.afterlogin').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('.beforelogin').css('display', 'block');
    $('.afterlogin').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

This gets you the display block or yes, or display none. To simply use jQuery to see if one is display and if so hide the other, you can do this:

```
var isDisplayed = $('.afterlogin').css('display', 'block');
var isNotDisplayed = $('.afterlogin').css('display', 'none');

if ($('.beforelogin').css('display') == 'none') {
  $(isDisplayed);
} else {
$(isNotDisplayed);
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with jQuery then you should take a beginners tutorial to show you where to put the scripts and all that stuff. YouTube has good videos for free.

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/timhjellum/25g3tjpk/)

Comment: Got any suggested videos for JQuery then? This is a bit confusing. 

Also why `temporarily`?

Can you edit your answer and place it in my code aswell as I am not sure how it should look under the header. Do I just copy-paste the code youn gave above? 

Also what do you mean with `display: none;`? Where do I use that (in my style.css) and for what class/id etc

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle I made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/timhjellum/25g3tjpk/

I will find a good tutorial but I need to get a beer.

Comment: You can probably accomplish what you need with simple JavaScript and you can get a good start here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

jQuery is JavaScript that uses a library to extend JavaScript. You need to link to a JavaScript file before jQuery will work.

Here's a good place to start: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

And here's a hosted jQuery file you need to link to. You can download the library and link to it but this will get you going faster:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: So TL;DR is w3 schools to be a webdev (easiest and simplest way possible)? Also I am on mobile so I will check your jsfiddle in 8-9 hours or so in the morning.

Comment: Yes, W3C is a good place to start and they have very basic tutorials. I would start with HTML, CSS, JavaScript then jQuery. From there you should start with YouTube as you will have an understanding of what to build on. 

This is a really good tut: [Git a Web Developer Job: Mastering the Modern Workflow](https://www.udemy.com/git-a-web-developer-job-mastering-the-modern-workflow/learn/v4/content) and the instructor has a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/LearnWebCode) channel and I highly recommend him.

Comment: The issue with your jsfiddle is the css and the html isnt exactly the same as mine, as you forgot the 4 buttons that should appear after login, and to the right of the balance, and their positoning got screwed up due to your CSS (Trying to fix it) but if you could help me and send me a fixed jsfiddle, that would be amazing!

Comment: I added the jquery code to my app.js, added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to my <head> in HTML but the login and logout are still present at the same time?

Comment: TL;DR - I answered your question and provided an example. I don't have time to re-write your app.

Comment: @Arszilla: Timber is quite correct. Readers want to help here, but repeated requests for just-a-bit-more-help are not fair, since they ask a lot of work of volunteers.